# Update policy ADX

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a source table and I want to use the update policy to copy the data from the source table to the target table but with an additional column that its value is obtained from an external table.

In the update policy I should copy the row from the origin table and look for the value I need to add in the external table through an Id.

I could easily use a view (join) but the problem is performance so I would like to have a table in ADX with the values I need.

The question is how the function should look like to copy the row from the source table to the target table by adding the column from the external table.

**Update: it seems that an external table cannot be used in an Update Policy. I get an error when I try to define it**

Exception: Request is invalid and cannot be processed: Semantic error: SEM0457: external_table(): usage is not allowed in this context.

Comment: What did you try? The example in the official documentation for the update policy looks like it is very close to what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: What about your statement - "I could easily use a view (join) but the problem is performance so I would like to have a table in ADX with the values I need.". Are you going to use an external table or not?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I would only use the external table to look up the id I need to add in the target table.

Answer (score 0):

your update policy command might look like this:

```
.alter table table2 policy update
@'[{"IsEnabled": true, "Source": "table1", "Query": "MyFunctionThatDoesTheLookup(table1, table2)", "IsTransactional": true, "PropagateIngestionProperties": false}]'
```

This means the table is getting data from table1. In between, you use a function. The function would look like this

```
.create-or-alter function 
MyFunctionThatDoesTheLookup
(
raw_table:(id:string,col1:string,col2:int), 
target_table:(id:string,col1:string,col2:int, col3:int)
) 
{
let mylookuptable = lookuptablename;
raw_table
| join kind=left mylookuptable | project col3 on id 
}
```

Comment: Ah, no. I feel good the way it is right now. Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: I might need some sleep . Anyways, the JOIN syntax looks wrong

Comment: @Werner the function would work well but when I try to define the update policy using the function with the external table (lookup table) I get an error. 
Exception: Request is invalid and cannot be processed: Semantic error: SEM0457: external_table(): usage is not allowed in this context.